# Javascript In Header Conflict Error - $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an interesting problem. I'm working on a wordpress/woocommerce child theme. In the header, I have javascript that helps create a loading overlay until everything on the webpage is loaded using document ready to add a class to the overlay element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ document.getElementById("page-load").className = "loaded" });
```

It's not working because of a javascript/jQuery conflict i reckon. I need this script in the header for obvious reasons(loaded asap), but I don't have control over the other scripts in the theme that are mostly in the footer.

How can I prevent the error:

> $ is not defined

Comment: Does the line happen before adding jQuery JS?

Comment: jQuery needs to be imported in the header before this script for `$` to be defined.

Comment: @Raptor - that shouldn't matter as long as jquery is being loaded somewhere (for example at the end of the html file, and this is at the top should still be okay ??  i think ? )

Comment: Even if you put the script in the header and load jQuery, the class will only assigned *after* the document was loaded. I wouldn't use jQuery just for `$(document).ready()`. Include your code at the bottom of the page and be done with it.

Comment: Did you try `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: @KraangPrime Incorrect. If the script is placed above the jQuery JS import line, it won't work at all.

Comment: @Raptor - i've never really noticed.  Typically i load jquery.min.js from CDN at the top and leave the rest to load at the bottom.   XD

Comment: @KraangPrime To expand on _@Raptor_'s point a little more, it's not that the code within the `$(document).ready` block will fail when these items are not loaded in order. Rather the browser will through an _Uncaught: Reference Error_ because the jQuery file will not have been parsed when this line is read and therefore `$` will be undefined. Since the browser parses synchronously (with a few exceptions), from top to bottom, the order in this case will indeed matter. `jquery.min.js` should come first.

Comment: @War10ck - makes sense.  I followed the logic, but thank you for taking the time to explain deeper.  It's just something I have never encounter due to how I handle prioritization of script loading.  Core at top - non-essential at bottom.  I don't use `async` as that can cause havoc by pseudo-randomizing the order in which scripts are loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a matter of waiting for document load you can try:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("page-load").className = "loaded";
});
```

Comment: Ouch, this looks so ancient.

Comment: @Raptor - but it definitely seems relevant.  Upvoted as the question this solution is for doesn't seem to even require jQuery (which is a waste of resource loading for just `$(document).ready()` as [Felix King](http://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) pointed out.